# Remove vim indents when I paste directly from system clipboard

Tags: command-line, vim, clipboard, vi

I have a problem with `vim` when I paste something it puts them in by placing  in each newline. How can I set default settings of `vim`.

Answer (score 3):

If you paste from the system clipboard, `vim` thinks the pasted text is user input and, if confiured to provide autoindent, `vim` makes it's job and automatically indents the code.

You can turn off that autoindent when you paste code into `vim` directly. Type that in the command mode:

```
:set paste
```

Now, your pasted code should be written without indent. To re-enable autoindent again use:

```
:set nopaste
```

To simplfy that, you can define a shortcut in you `.vimrc` as follows:

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

Now, when you press <kbd>F2</kbd> in insert mode to have the desired behavior. Then press again <kbd>F2</kbd>, to work with autoindent as before.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt this neat automation from [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode), write the following into your `.vimrc` file

```
let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[?2004h"
let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[?2004l"

inoremap <special> <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin()

function! XTermPasteBegin()
  set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
  set paste
  return ""
endfunction
```

and it will switch on and off paste mode for you.

Using `vim` within `tmux` can be a little bit tricky, as you **may** (I use "may" because I do not have to double escape when I am inside `tmux`) have to double escape using

```
function! WrapForTmux(s)
  if !exists('$TMUX')
    return a:s
  endif

  let tmux_start = "\<Esc>Ptmux;"
  let tmux_end = "\<Esc>\\"

  return tmux_start . substitute(a:s, "\<Esc>", "\<Esc>\<Esc>", 'g') . tmux_end
endfunction

let &t_SI .= WrapForTmux("\<Esc>[?2004h")
let &t_EI .= WrapForTmux("\<Esc>[?2004l")

function! XTermPasteBegin()
  set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
  set paste
  return ""
endfunction

inoremap <special> <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste directly from clipboard (`"*`) using vim's `paste` (`p`) instruction: `"*p` without having to enter `INSERT` mode.

Since the above won't work when you're connected to a remote terminal, chaos's suggestion would be your best option.

[vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) adds a nice shortcut `yo` and `yO` which automatically does `set paste`, insert a new line after/before the cursor's current line and then `set nopaste` once you exit `INSERT` mode.